# In Adobe Illustrator, I need to combine multiple compound paths and paths into a single object or shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I have a floorplan diagram which consists of over 100 different paths and compound paths.  I need to combine all of these elements into a single shape layer.

I have tried selecting all of them and using both the "Unite" and "Merge" options in the Pathfinder window.  This didn't work.  I have also tried "Make Compound Shape."  Not only does this not create a single shape layer, it also messes up the drawing by creating blocks of color where there were none before.

I have even tried a hack workaround by copying all of these paths and compound paths in Illustrator, pasting them into Photoshop, and creating a single shape layer out that, which I could then copy back into Illustrator.  The trouble is, as soon as I click "combine," Photoshop freezes and crashes.  I guess the shape just has too many points for it to handle.  It's too large a file.

What can I do to create a single shape layer?

Comment: is this related to scripting illustrator or simply using it's interface ?

Comment: Just using its interface.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming. Perhaps you could ask this question on the SuperUser stack exchange site?

Answer (score 0):

A picture would help but I would try the [Shape builder tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uM0mHkLM1g). It's very useful for complex shapes.